# Custom access for a web-based custom type

Tags: 9

For my Drupal site, I made a custom type named MyCoolCustomType. I'd like to grant access to view this custom type only to certain condition on user role and properties of the custom content itself (for example, the ModerationState of the content).

I'm quite confused about how to process.

Thanks to a class that extends `RouteSubscriberBase`, I'm trying to modify the route entity.node.canonical to change the `requirements` part. In this part, I'm going to use a dedicated service for `_custom_access`.

Where is a good place to filter only MyCoolCustomType, a service or a subscriber?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the route subscribers implemented by a Drupal core module, the [`Drupal\content_moderation\Routing\ContentModerationRouteSubscriber`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_moderation%21src%21Routing%21ContentModerationRouteSubscriber.php/class/ContentModerationRouteSubscriber/9) class alters the routes in its [`setLatestRevisionFlag()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_moderation%21src%21Routing%21ContentModerationRouteSubscriber.php/function/ContentModerationRouteSubscriber%3A%3AsetLatestRevisionFlag/9) method (called by [`ContentModerationRouteSubscriber::alterRoutes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_moderation%21src%21Routing%21ContentModerationRouteSubscriber.php/function/ContentModerationRouteSubscriber%3A%3AalterRoutes/9).

```php
// Only set the flag on entity types which are revisionable.
[$entity_type] = explode('.', $entity_form, 2);
if (!isset($this->getModeratedEntityTypes()[$entity_type]) || !$this->getModeratedEntityTypes()[$entity_type]->isRevisionable()) {
  return;
}

$parameters = $route->getOption('parameters') ?: [];

foreach ($parameters as &$parameter) {
  if (isset($parameter['type']) && $parameter['type'] === 'entity:' . $entity_type && !isset($parameter['load_latest_revision'])) {
    $parameter['load_latest_revision'] = TRUE;
  }
}

$route->setOption('parameters', $parameters);
```

Essentially, that code first verifies the entity type is one the module handles and then alters the route definition.
The same should be done from your code: The route subscriber verifies the route is for an handled entity, and then calls `$route->addRequirements()` to add its own `_custom_access`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't even manage to get the node's content type. Is it better to check it inside the service I mention in the _custom_access section I add ?